# gsd-housekeeping makes noise and data disappears

Tags: hard-drive

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.
Today I've copied ~2TB from one partition to another.
The usage of partition became over 90% (by `df`).
Then I've noticed a noisy HDD I/O. 
`htop` showed it was the `gsd-housekeeping` process.
It contitued about 15 minutes.
Then I've taken a look at my partition and seen ~3TB of *old* data disappeared from the partition.

What have happened? Can `gsd-housekeeping` silently remove old data from overflowed partitions? How can I check it?

Comment: Three times I have lost plenty of files the last months (Nov-Dec) with ubuntu 18.04.  The log analysis has shown the gsd-housekeeping daemon crash near the time of the collapse. The last time this crash appeared in parallel on my laptop with ubuntu 18.04, without the data loss, fortunately. 1st I reinstalled U1804, 2nd I changed the HD, 3rd I throwed away the PC. I am afraid of a rare Ubuntu problem also. All what is gone is from $HOME directory.